# Navigate through various child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I am working on website similar to http://keepearthquakesweird.com/.

I am not good in jQuery except the basic stuff but have created the layout in html5 and css3. The problem I am having is if you see on the website after clicking the enter link it takes you to a grid.
I have created exact grid and able to pull up various div content when user clicks on various links by the following approach (you can see my code below) using css3 + jquery.
 So the question is that is there a better approach for pulling up the divs when user click on the link. the main question is I need the next previous button as in the website mentioned when you click any alphabet, so you can navigate through the description divs. 

Looking for some honest advice and solution :)

```js
$('a#alpha').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

  $("#container > div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-id') == id) {
      $(this).toggleClass('show-content');
    }
  });
});

$("a#cls").click(function() {
  $("#container > div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('show-content')) {
      $(this).removeClass('show-content');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#container div {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform: -webkit-translateY(100%);
  -moz-transform: -moz-translateY(100%);
  -o-transform: -o-translateY(100%);
  transition: .4s ease-in all;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in all;
  -moz-transition: .4s ease-in all;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 1;
}
.closeBtn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
#content-1 {
  background: #333;
}
#content-2 {
  background: #ff0;
}
#content-3 {
  background: #f00;
}
.show-content {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  z-index: 5 !important;
  transform: translateY(0%) !important;
  -webkit-transform: -webkit-translateY(0%) !important;
  -moz-transform: -moz-translateY(0%) !important;
  -o-transform: -o-translateY(0%) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-id="01" id="alpha">Link to pull div</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-id="02" id="alpha">Link to pull div</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-id="03" id="alpha">Link to pull div</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content-1" data-id="01">
    <a href="#0" class="closeBtn" id="cls">X</a>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content-2" data-id="02">
    <a href="#0" class="closeBtn" id="cls">X</a>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="content-3" data-id="03">
    <a href="#0" class="closeBtn" id="cls">X</a>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @ManojKumar his first version seemed different; but then realized they are *both* broke/non-functional, so I deleted the comment, before you replied:) I'm having a difficult time understanding what the issue is or what is trying to be shown in [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/2xLzrjjg/); if they are actually broke or I missing what it exemplifies

Comment: @Quoid Oh no. I just aligned the code :) Let's wait for OP to be clear about it.

Comment: @ManojKumar it happened again! :) yes I agree

Comment: Sorry , is there any kind of confusion about the question? if yes all I want is after you click on the link and the divs are shown , I want next and previous buttons to go to the next div and the previous one... if I am being unclear about any thing let me know :)